# How to get transfer data from stripe using payment id and account id (.Net)

Tags: .net-core, stripe-payments

I am trying to get transfer related data from stripe

```
        TransferService service = new TransferService();
        TransferListOptions stripeTransferList = new TransferListOptions
        {
            Destination = accountId,
            Limit = 100
        };
        var list = await service.ListAsync(stripeTransferList);
        var finalData = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DestinationPaymentId == paymentId);
```

so when I try to search **`paymentId`** from that list I was not able to find any because the page limit is 100 only

```
 Limit = 100
```

how to fetch all the data and filter from that??

Answer (score 1):

The stripe-dotnet library supports automatic pagination and it's documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=dotnet).

This lets you paginate through all the data in your account based on specific criteria that you passed as parameters. For example you can list all `Transfer` objects made to a specific connected account this way:

```
TransferService service = new TransferService();
TransferListOptions listOptions = new TransferListOptions
{
  Destination = "acct_123456",
  Limit = 100
};
foreach (var transfer in service.ListAutoPaging(listOptions)) {
  // Do something with this Transfer
}
```

Now, this allows you to iterate over every `Transfer` but if you have a lot of data this could be quite slow. An alternative would be to start from the charge id, the `py_123456` that you have from your connected account. If you know which account this charge was created on, you can fetch it directly via the API. This is done using the Retrieve Charge [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve) along with passing the connected account id as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header).

The `Charge` [resource](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object) has the `source_transfer` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-source_transfer) which is the id of the `Transfer` (tr_123) from the platform that created this charge. You can also use the [Expand feature](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects), which lets you fetch the entire `Transfer` object back to get some detailed information about it.

The code would look like this

```
var transferOptions = new TransferGetOptions{};
transferOptions.AddExpand("source_transfer");

var requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.StripeAccount = "acct_12345";

TransferService service = new TransferService();
Charge charge = service.Get(transferOptions, requestOptions);

// Access information about the charge or the associated transfer
var transferId = charge.SourceTransfer.Id;
var transferAmount = charge.SourceTransfer.TransferData.Amount;
```